# Unable to pull my private image from docker hub

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

After I upgrade my docker from 1.8.2-el7 to version 1.12.6, its failing to pull my private images from docker hub.

I could able to perform the list image command

```
sudo docker -H tcp://test-app01.local:2376 images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
account/image1   tag1                a4c286f0ec9e        10 hours ago        864.7 MB
ubuntu                    latest              d355ed3537e9        8 days ago          119.2 MB
account/image1   tag2          4abd8c3ed720        3 months ago        878.8 MB
```

But it's unable to pull latest image from repo with successful login.

```
sudo docker -H tcp://test-app01.local:2376 login -u username -p password
Login Succeeded

sudo docker -H tcp://test-app01.local:2376 pull  account/image1:tag1
Using default tag: tag1
Pulling repository docker.io/account/image1
Error: image account/image1:latest not found
```

Can somebody please assist to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `image` command, you have only `tag1` and `tag2` image tags.

If you don't specify any, docker will look for `latest` which you don't have. So pull as this for tag1:

```
sudo docker -H tcp://test-app01.local:2376 pull  account/image1:tag1
```

Or this for tag2:

```
sudo docker -H tcp://test-app01.local:2376 pull  account/image1:tag2
```

Comment: True,If I don't mention anything it should have pulled the default ( latest ) image.

Comment: Seems like the issue is to pull my private image from docker hub . If I change the image from private to public its able to pull it.